# Incompatibility between lineno and equation*

Tags: equations, incompatibility, line-numbering

In addition to a lot of others incompatibilities, also there is one between `lineno` and `equation*`.

Is there any chance to have the `lineno` package updated to solve this problem? Does anybody here knows if the maintainers would work on it?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}\linenumbers
This is the first line. Here comes a numbered equation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq.1}
a=b
\end{equation} and here is the first line after equation~\eqref{eq.1}.

New paragraph here and now comes a stared \texttt{equation} environment:
\begin{equation*}\label{eq.2}
c=d
\end{equation*}
and here is the line after the unumbered equation.

Finally, last paragraph with a display math environment:
\[ e=f\] and the last line. Bye!
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The incompatibility is somehow stated in the documentation of `lineno`

Comment: Yes, and a workaround also.  Put your math stuff in a linenomsth environment, iirc.

Comment: @JPi: As far as I know this is exactly what does not work for `amsmath`'s `equation*` environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate this correction around the `equation*` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lineno}

\expandafter\let\expandafter\oldequation\csname equation*\endcsname
\expandafter\let\expandafter\endoldequation\csname endequation*\endcsname

\def\lneq{\linenomath\oldequation}
\def\endlneq{\endoldequation\endlinenomath}
\renewenvironment{equation*}{%
  \ifLineNumbers
    \let\mathenvironment\lneq
    \let\endmathenvironment\endlneq
  \else
    \let\mathenvironment\oldequation
    \let\endmathenvironment\endoldequation
  \fi 
  \begin{mathenvironment}}
  {\end{mathenvironment}}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
This is the first line. Here comes a numbered equation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq.1}
a=b
\end{equation} 
and here is the first line after equation~\eqref{eq.1}.

New paragraph here and now comes a stared \texttt{equation} environment:
\begin{equation*}\label{eq.2}
c=d
\end{equation*}
and here is the line after the unumbered equation.

Finally, last paragraph with a display math environment:
\[
  e=f
\]
and the last line. Bye!
\end{document}
```

Comment: This could be inserted in a new version of the package. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine for me:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}\linenumbers
This is the first line. Here comes a numbered equation:
\begin{linenomath}
\begin{equation}\label{eq.1}
a=b
\end{equation} 
\end{linenomath}
and here is the first line after equation~\eqref{eq.1}.

New paragraph here and now comes a stared \texttt{equation} environment:
\begin{linenomath}
\begin{equation*}\label{eq.2}
c=d
\end{equation*}
\end{linenomath}
and here is the line after the unumbered equation.

Finally, last paragraph with a display math environment:
\[ e=f\] and the last line. Bye!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. It works for me also. But it would be nice to have a new version of the package solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

With my setup, [@Werner's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/265864/5699) works but inserts an extraneous space at the beginning of the line following the `\end{equation*}`. The following code, based on his answer, seems to work for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,lineno}

\expandafter\let\expandafter\oldequationstar\csname equation*\endcsname
\expandafter\let\expandafter\endoldequationstar\csname endequation*\endcsname

\expandafter\def\csname equation*\endcsname{%
  \ifLineNumbers%
  \expandafter\linenomath%
  \fi%
  \oldequationstar%
}

\expandafter\def\csname endequation*\endcsname{%
  \endoldequationstar%
  \ifLineNumbers%
  \def\maybeendlinenomath{\expandafter\endlinenomath}%
  \else
  \def\maybeendlinenomath{}%
  \fi%
  \expandafter\maybeendlinenomath%
}
\begin{document}
\linenumbers
This is the first line. Here comes a numbered equation:
\begin{equation}\label{eq.1}
a=b
\end{equation} 
and here is the first line after equation~\eqref{eq.1}.

New paragraph here and now comes a stared \texttt{equation} environment:
\begin{equation*}\label{eq.2}
c=d
\end{equation*}
and here is the line after the unumbered equation.

Finally, last paragraph with a display math environment:
\[
  e=f
\]
and the last line. Bye!
\end{document}
```